# How to calculate the difference between 2 HTML5 time input types in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

this is my markup

```
<input type="time" name="fromTime" id="fromTime" ng-model="newleave.fromTime" class="form-control" />
<input type="time" name="toTime" id="toTime" ng-model="newleave.toTime" class="form-control" ng-blur="calculatehours()"/>
<input type="time" name="Hours" id="Hours" ng-model="newleave.hours" class="form-control" readonly />
```

and following is my angular code

```
$scope.calculatehours = function(){
$scope.newleave.hours = $scope.newleave.toTime - $scope.newleave.fromTime;
console.log('hours',$scope.newleave.hours);
}
```

in console it is printing the value 360000 but i am not able to bind it in my third input type="time".
for that i am getting

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `3600000` to be a date
```

Comment: `new Date(3600000).toISOString().match(/(\d\d:)+\d\d/g)[0]`

Comment: @dandavis—and if the difference is more than 24 hours? ;-)

Comment: @dandavis
your thing is just converting '3600000' into '01:00:00' but still i cant bind it with my third input element and i am getting an error

    'Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `01:00:00` to be a date'

Comment: do i need to change my input element type 'time' to 'date'.
BTW my problem solved.i changed it to text but in case...U know..if i need in 'time'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear to me what the value represents (seconds or milliseconds) and what the value you require in return. In one place you have 360000 and another 3600000 (an extra zero).

If it's milliseconds, and you require a string in the format h:mm:ss, then you can use a function like:

```js
/*  Convert milliseconds to time in hh:mm:ss format
**  @param {number} ms - milliseconds to convert
**  @returns {string} time in hh:mm:ss format
*/
var msToTime = (function() {
  function pad(n){return (n < 10? '0':'') + n}
  return function(ms) {
    return pad(ms/3600000 | 0) + ':' +
           pad((ms%3600000)/60000 | 0) + ':' +
           pad((ms%60000)/1000 | 0);
  }
}());

alert(msToTime(3600000));
```

If it's seconds, remove 3 zeros from the divisors. If you don't want a leading zero on the hour value, don't use *pad* on it.